# Model not accesseble outside namespace

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im trying to bind my knockout array to a table, but cant reach the model outside the javascript function.

Here is my javascript code

```
(function (conf, $, undefined) {

    var model = { menuRows : [], orderRows : [], menuDetails : null };

    conf.getMenuRows = function () {

        $.get("/orderpackage/row", function (data) {
            model.orderRows = data;
        });

    };

    conf.getMenuRows();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

}(window.conf = window.conf || {}, jQuery));
```

And this is the HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Beskrivning</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.orderRows">
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

model.orderRows is not found.

Cant understand what im doing wrong here.

Comment: That's definitely javascript code and not java :)

Answer (score 2):

your models are not using the observable array function. You will need something like the following:

```
function Model() {
 var self = this();

 self.menuRows = ko.observableArray();
 self.orderRows = ko.observableArray();
 self.getMenuRows = function() {
  $.get("/orderpackage/row", function (data) {
       self.orderRows = ko.observableArray(data)
    });
 ....
}
```

Then you can call

```
(function (conf, $, undefined) {

var model = Model();


model.getMenuRows();
ko.applyBindings(model);

}(window.conf = window.conf || {}, jQuery));
```

Then you should be able to bind like you are doing in your HTML.
More tutorials can be found here: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

If you then want to bind to items in each of the array elements, the description for example, you will need to create an additional model definition for the row and parse the data returned from your api to the model type.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution

```
(function (conf, $, undefined) {

    var model = {
        menuRows: ko.observableArray([]),
        order: ko.observableArray([]),
        menuDetails: ko.observable()
    };

    conf.getMenuRows = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/orderpackage/row",
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            contenttype: "application/json;utf8"
        }).done(function (data) {
            model.order(data.model);
        });
    };

    conf.getMenuRows();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

}(window.conf = window.conf || {}, jQuery));
```